# Set combination question

Tags: set, permutation, combinatorics

Got this as an homework assignment and not really sure where to start!

Given the set `{1,2,3,4}`, you can form six combinations of length two from that set, viz:

```
{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}
```

If I was to choose one of the combinations, (`{1,2}` for example), how can I tell how many of the others are not disjoint to it? In this case it is four: `{1,3},{1,4},{2,3}{2,4}`

Not really sure about how to go about this mathematically, any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Number of subsets that can be formed from a set of `n` items taking `r` items at a time is

```
total = P(n, r) = n! / (r! * (n - r)!)
```

Let `s` be the selected combination. To find the number of subsets that are not disjoint with `s`, we start by finding the number of subsets that are disjoint with `s` - those sets that doesn't have any items in `s` (lets call that number `k`). Thus `k` is the number of subsets that can be formed from a set of `n - r` items, taking `r` at a time.

```
k = P(n - r, r) = (n - r)! / (r! * (n - r - r)!)
  = (n - r)! / (r! * (n - 2r)!)
```

Thus, the number of subsets disjoint with the selected set is:

```
total - k = P(n, r) - P(n - r, r)
```

Remember that this includes the selected subset `s`. Subtract one from this to get the number of disjoint sets with `s`.

Consider the following example:

> `//Let n = 6 and r = 2`
>   `total = P(n, r) = n! / (r! * (n - r)!) = 6! / (2! * 4!) = 15`
>
> `k = P(n - r, r) = (n - r)! / (r! * (n - 2r)!) = 4! / (2! * 2!) = 6`
>   `answer = 15 - 6 = 9;`
>   `answer excluding the selected set s = 8`

```
//Super set: 
  {123456}
//Possible sub sets: 
  {12,13,14,15,16,23,24,25,26,34,35,36,45,46,56}  //15 items

//Let the selected set be {12}, then sets without 1 and 2: 
  {34,35,36,45,46,56} //6 items

//9 sets (including the selected set) are not disjoint with the selected set
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start by reading some book or articles on [combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) ..

If you can program, [this library](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
For each item in my combination ( 1 then 2 ) do the following
* For each item in the set (1, 2, 3, then 4) do the following
** if set item is different from both combination item 1 and 2
*** print out combination item and print out set item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) or better [Permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Answer (score 0):

The sets *X* = {*a*, *b*} and *Y* are disjoint if *a* and *b* both do not appear in *Y*. Therefore, *X* and *Y* are *not* disjoint if *a* appears in *Y* or *b* appears in *Y*.

To find out how many other sets are not disjoint with {*a*, *b*}, consider all the possibilities: In general all the sets with two elements that are not disjoint with {*a*, *b*} are of the form {*a*, *x*} or {*b*, *x*}, for any *x* in the original set. If the original set had *n* elements, then there are *n* possibilities for {*a*, *x*} and another *n* for
{*b*, *x*}, for a total of 2*n*.

However, {*a*, *b*} is both of the form {*a*, *x*} (for *x* = *b*) and of the form {*b*, *x*} (for *x* = *a*), so we are counting it twice. We must count it zero times, because {*a*, *b*} is the same set as the one we were starting with. So we subtract 2, for a total of 2*n* - 2.

But we're still counting {*a*, *a*} (for *x* = *a*) and {*b*, *b*} (for *x* = *b*). But those only contain one element each ({*a*, *a*} = {*a*} and {*b*, *b*} = {*b*}), so we shouldn't count them. Therefore we subtract 2, for a total of 2*n* - 4.

For your example, {1, 2, 3, 4} gives n = 4, so the number of elements not disjoint with {1, 2} is 2*4 - 4 = 4.